# How to run multiple if conditions correctly in batch script

Tags: batch-file

My script is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Current_Node=Node1
set counter=0

if "%Current_Node%" == "Node5" ( GOTO CASE_%counter%
:CASE_0
  ECHO  "case 0"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_1
   ECHO  "case 1"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_2
  ECHO  "case 2"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_3
 ECHO  "case 3"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
 :CASE_4
  ECHO  "case 4"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
 :CASE_5
ECHO  "case 5"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
GOTO END_SWITCH
:END_SWITCH
 set  /A counter=%counter%+1
 if %counter% LEQ 3 (
 echo helloooooo
 GOTO CASE_%counter% 
) ELSE ( 
echo "NO MORE EXE'S AVAILABLE"
)
) 
)
pause 

if "%Current_Node%" == "Node1" ( GOTO CASE_%counter%
 :CASE_0
  ECHO  "case 0"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_1
   ECHO  "case 1"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_2
  ECHO  "case 2"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_3
 ECHO  "case 3"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
 :CASE_4
  ECHO  "case 4"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
 :CASE_5
ECHO  "case 5"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH
:END_SWITCH
 set  /A counter=%counter%+1
 if %counter% LEQ 5 (
GOTO CASE_%counter% 
) ELSE ( 
echo "NO MORE EXE'S AVAILABLE"
)
)  
)
pause
```

Now , when i run this i do not get the correct number of exe's running. I am not getting where is the problem.

This problem i do not face when i run single if condition , its happening only when i add multiple if conditions. So, kindly help out.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is hard to read but this will check two conditions.

```
if "%Current_Node%" == "Node5" if %counter% EQU 0 (
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
)

if "%Current_Node%" == "Node5" if %counter% EQU 1 (
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your program is supposed to be doing (e.g. when does CurrentNode ever get set to "Node5"?), so I cannot offer an altered version, but in general, you'll have to implement the logical operators yourself. `SET /A` has some bitwise operators that will work if you evaluate each condition by itself and save the result in a variable.

Logical AND is simple. You just chain two if statements together. The others are more work. One possibility is to do them arithmetically. Here's a logical OR (implemented using `SET /A`'s bitwise OR operator).

```
IF "%Current_Node%"=="Node5" (SET COND_A=1) ELSE (SET COND_A=0)
IF "%counter%"=="1" (SET COND_B=1) ELSE (SET COND_B=0)
SET /A "_OR=COND_A | COND_B"
IF "%_OR%"=="1" (
    REM Stuff to do when OR condition is true
) ELSE (
    REM Stuff to do when OR condition is false
)
```

Exclusive OR can be implemented similarly, using the bitwise XOR (`^`) operator.
IFF (if and only if) would need to be implemented using a comparison for equality.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at your code, I see at least one fundamental problem: you're attempting variable substitution inside the same `()` block where the variable is set. Though I cannot find actual documentation (about CMD parsing **at all**—I presume none exists), it seems that CMD parses/evaluates everything within `()` before it runs anything in it, and any variable substitution using `%var_name%` gets replaced *before* any of the statements are ever run.

Here's an example:

```
if "%Current_Node%" == "Node5" ( GOTO CASE_%counter%
REM ... other code removed for brevity ...
:END_SWITCH
 set  /A counter=%counter%+1
 if %counter% LEQ 3 (
 echo helloooooo
 GOTO CASE_%counter% 
) 
)
```

If you wish to do this, you need to use Delayed Expansion, which can be enabled in the script (usually at the beginning, but at least some time before you use it) with `SETLOCAL`

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Delayed expansion waits until the code is executed before expanding variables. It also uses a different character to signify expansion: `!`. The snippet above would then be:

```
if "%Current_Node%" == "Node5" ( GOTO CASE_%counter%
REM ... other code removed for brevity ...
:END_SWITCH
 set  /A counter=counter+1
 if !counter! LEQ 3 (
 echo helloooooo
 GOTO CASE_!counter!
) 
)
```

BTW, `SET /A` allows you to use variable names without the expansion character. Also, the operators that come with IF are lexical (string comparison), so they won't do straight numerical comparison. For example, try:

```
IF "10" LEQ "5" ECHO Less Than
IF "10" LEQ "05" ECHO Less Than
```

Only the second one will produce the expected results. Padding numbers with zeros (or spaces) is the only way to get something like numerical comparisons using lexical comparison operators. In the code you've provided, you won't see a problem until `counter` gets to 10, and then `10 LEQ 5` will evaluate to true.

Comment: current_node is to be set by user itself for example when one sets the current_node equal to node5 then the  corresponding if condition will be executed i.e if set Current_Node=Node1 then if "%Current_Node%" == "Node1" will be executed similarly if i set Current_Node=Node5 then if "%Current_Node%" == "Node5" will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't jump within a block. Labels must be unique within a batch.

```
if "%Current_Node%"=="Node5" (GOTO CASE_%counter%)
if "%Current_Node%"=="Node1" (GOTO KASE_%counter%)
echo neither node1 nor node 5
goto :eof

:CASE_0
  ECHO  "case 0"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_1
   ECHO  "case 1"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH
:CASE_2
 ... and so on...
:END_SWITCH
set  /A counter=%counter%+1
if %counter% LEQ 3 (
 echo helloooooo
 GOTO CASE_%counter% 
) ELSE ( 
echo "NO MORE EXE'S AVAILABLE"
)
pause
goto :eof

:KASE_0
  ECHO  "kase 0"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO END_SWITCH_1
:KASE_1
   ECHO  "kase 1"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
 GOTO END_SWITCH_1
:KASE_2
 ... and so on...
:END_SWITCH_1
set  /A counter=%counter%+1
if %counter% LEQ 3 (
 echo helloooooo again!
 GOTO KASE_%counter% 
) ELSE ( 
echo "NO MORE EXE'S AVAILABLE for node 1"
)
pause
goto :eof
```

Having said that, your example is artificial; what you are attempting to do is murky.

Another approach could be

```
set Current_Node=Node1
for /L %%a in (0,1,5) do call Case_%current_node%_%%a
goto :eof

:CaSE_Node1_0
  ECHO  "CaSE_Node1_0"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO :EOF

:CaSE_Node1_1
  ECHO  "CaSE_Node1_1"
  start sample1.exe -configuration 
  start sample2.exe -configuration 
  start sample3.exe -configuration 
  GOTO :EOF
 ...etc.
```

but that would entail understanding what you actually want to do with `counter`.

Need more explanation of your objective - there are other structures, depending on what is you want to do.

Comment: well,thank you so much i was making mistake in naming of labels only now all conditions are meeting properly and in output i see now running the number of exe's  as expected.

Comment: Actually, labels do not need to be unique, but they should be if you want others to understand your code. Behavior with duplicate labels is totally predictable, as long as you know the entire script. Upon CALL or GOTO, the batch engine searches from the current file position and stops at the first matching label found. If not found by the end of the script, then it loops back and searches from the top of the script. If it reaches the original CALL or GOTO without finding the label, then you get the label not found error.

Comment: @dbenham the potential for abuse, confusion and obfuscation boggles the mind. Takes me back to the evils of layout-dependent COBOL `PERFORM THROUGH` structures and PhD students that insisted on alphabetising paragraph names. Fortunately, these heretics don't seem to have been missed - at least, the authorities don't seem to have discovered the bodies. Best keep that characteristic firmly under out hats, eh?