# How to use For loop query

Tags: batch-file

The syntax of for loop in batch script is as:

for example I want to do something x=6 times

```
for /l %%a in (1 ,1, 6)
```

where 1,1,6 means:

- start = 1
- increment per step = 1
- end = 6

Now, I want to know :

1. Does the start here implies the index and can I keep it 0 also?
2. If I do the following:

   ```
   set counter=0
   for /l %%a in (0 ,%counter% , 6) do (
       GOTO CASE_%counter%

       :CASE_0
       // body

       :CASE_1
       // body
       .....
       :CASE_6
       //body

       GOTO END_SWITCH

       :END_SWITCH
       set /A counter=%counter%+1
       if %counter% LEQ 6 (
           GOTO CASE_%counter% 
       )
   )
   pause
   ```

The above code does not work but if I set `counter=1` in the first line in above code it works fine.

So, does it mean that I need to always start my counter from 1? Can I not start it from 0?

Comment: also take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27707122/2152082  Especially at the "update" section (delayed expansion)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your loop isn't working is because you have `Counter=0` and are using it as your increment amount. So every time through the loop, it is incremented by 0; hence it will run forever.

Changing `Counter=1` will run for `0..6` (7 total times), each time incrementing by 1.

---

There are some errors in your loop you may want to take a look at. You are incrementing `counter` within the loop - I don't think this is doing what you want it to do. `%%a` will be the variable which increments from your defined min/max values and the `FOR` construct will handle this for you.

Suggested code:

```
set counter=1
for /l %%a in (0 ,%counter% , 6) do (
    if "%%a"=="0" (
        [do stuff]
    )
    if "%%a"=="1" (
        [do stuff]
    )
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanky ou so much, it helped me a lot in figuring out the main root cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your example, you have told the program to increment in steps of 0, that is why it did not work.

There is no problem with starting with index of 0. Counter of 0 however will not work.

Comment: Thanks it was of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The true root cause of your problem is usage of `goto` within `for` which is simply not possible; `goto` breaks the `for` loop context, so the command interpreter behaves as the commands in the `for` body were outside of `for` as soon as a `goto` is executed.

As a work-around you could place all code of the `for` body in a sub-routine (let's call it `:SUB_SWITCH`), and put `call :SUB_SWITCH` into the `for` body as the only command.

You can find a similar problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127902/5047996).

---

To answer your primary question:
Yes, you can start with `0` or *any* other (integer) value, even negative ones.
(You can even set the increment to `0` to set up an endless loop (however, start must be equal to or less than end for this to work, otherwise the loop does never iterate).)